# Why does it say $con is an undefined variable when I defined it on line 2?

Tags: php, mysqli

I get a strange error.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testdatabase");

class database{
    public function select($tableName){
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ".$tableName);       
    }       
}

$database = new database();
?>
```

The error message is that $con is an undefined variable. But I define $con on line number 2?

When I var_dump con it also says NULL.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot use global variables inside a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access to your $con var in a method or function, you have to globalize it inside your code :

```
public function select($tableName){
    global $con;
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ".$tableName);       
}
```

**But you shouldn't do that, globals are evil !**

This is how your code should be :

```
<?php
class database{
    protected $con;

    public function __construct($host, $user, $password, $dbname){
        $this->con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbname);
    }

    public function select($tableName){
        $result = mysqli_query($this->con,"SELECT * FROM ".$tableName);       
    }       
}

$database = new database("localhost", "root", "", "testdatabase");
?>
```

Comment: Using a single connection through your entire app with no pooling is going to be super, super slow.

Comment: There is no connection pooling in PHP.

Comment: PHP begs to differ: [persistent connections in mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php).

Answer (score 2):

The connection `$con` is available in the global scope.  What you likely want to do is inject your mysql connection (in the form of mysqli object) in the constructor for your Database object. Here is a simple example:

```
<?php
$mysqli= new mysqli("localhost","root","","testdatabase");

class database{
    protected $mysqli = null;
    public function __contruct(MySQLI $mysqli = NULL) {
        $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
    }

    public function select($tableName){
        $result = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM ".$tableName);       
    }       
}

$database = new database($mysqli);
?>
```

Note that since you are trying to go with an object-oriented paradigm, you might as well use mysqli in an object oriented fashion.

Comment: to me it makes more sense to declare the connection inside the construct function instead of creating a dependency.

Comment: @kasperTaeymans Dependency injection is much more flexible.  That way you don't couple your class to any specific DB-connection logic.  You could pass any mysqli object that your system may instantiate and pass it to this class.

Answer (score 0):

Add a construct function to your class and declare your connection inside this function.

```
class database{
    private $con;
    public function __construct(){
       $this->con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testdatabase"); 
    }
    public function select($tableName){
        $result = mysqli_query($this->con,"SELECT * FROM ".$tableName);       
    }       
}

$database = new database();
```